# Resolving "ssl handshake failure" error in PostgresQL

Tags: postgresql, ssl, openssl

I would like to connect to my Postgres 8.3 database using SSL from my XP client using OpenSSL. This works fine without SSL. When I try it with SSL (no client certificate), I get the error:

```
error:140790E5:SSL routines:SSL23_WRITE:ssl handshake failure
```

I suspect that I need to change something with the Postgres configuration but I don't know what. I have followed the instructions in the Postgres manual for SSL including creating a self-signed certificate. In my pg_hba.conf there is a line:

```
host  dbname  loginname   123.45.67.89/32  md5
```

Is there something else I should be looking at?

Comment: Good question, but the solution is not likely to require programming. Probably get better response on serverfault.com

Answer (score 1):

This is an error inside OpenSSL. It doesn't sound like a PostgreSQL configuration problem. However, it could be an OpenSSL config problem - check if you have any non-detailt openssl.conf on the machine(s).

Also, what version of OpenSSL do you have on the server, and what OS is that? If you have a really old one, that could be the reason.

Comment: The only config file I see on the server is openssl.cnf and it looks OK to me.  The version of OpenSSL on the server is 0.9.8g and on the client is 0.9.8j. Might be worthwhile to update the version on the server. Thanks.

Comment: Still the same issue after updating the server to 0.9.8k